# Prefixing iostat with the current time

Tags: linux, shell-scripting

I'd like to prefix my `iostat` output for device **sda** with a timestamp. *Y-m-d H:M:S* would suffice. This does not seem so straightforward however. My first attempt was simply:

```
# vi just_echo                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
mystamp=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
cat /dev/stdin | grep sda | sed "s/sda/$mystamp/"

# iostat 5 | ./just_echo
```

This doesn't produce any ouput however. If I remove `sed` I do get some output but what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172307/duplicate-questions-on-other-se-sites

Question is answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26728/prepending-a-timestamp-to-each-line-of-output-from-a-command).

[moreutils](http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/moreutils/) includes `ts` which does this quite nicely:

`command | ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]'`

It eliminates the need for a loop too, every line of output will have a timestamp put on it.

```
$ echo -e "foo\nbar\nbaz" | ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]'
[2011-12-13 22:07:03] foo
[2011-12-13 22:07:03] bar
[2011-12-13 22:07:03] baz
```

You want to know when that server came back up you restarted? Just run `ping | ts` , problem solved :D.

---

If you want different methods not using `ts`:

### POSIX shell

Bear in mind that since many shells store their strings internally as cstrings, if the input contains the null character (`\0`), it may cause the line to end prematurely.

```
command | while IFS= read -r line; do printf '[%s] %s\n' "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')" "$line"; done
```

### GNU awk

```
command | gawk '{ print strftime("[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]"), $0 }'
```

### Perl

```
command | perl -pe 'use POSIX strftime; print strftime "[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S] ", localtime'
```

### Python

```
command | python -c 'import sys,time;sys.stdout.write("".join(( " ".join((time.strftime("[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]", time.localtime()), line)) for line in sys.stdin )))'
```

### Ruby

```
command | ruby -pe 'print Time.now.strftime("[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S] ")'
```

Comment: Say, that's a great find! Definitely using that. I am really wondering how to accomplish this with a simple shell script however. Curious why it won't work.

Comment: It's in the other answer, e.g.: `iostat | gawk '{ print strftime("[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]"), $0 }'`, added it to the answer.

Comment: Ahhh ok, I see it now: `One problem here is that many programs turn on even more output buffering when their stdout is a pipe instead of the terminal`  I'll bet if I let `iostat` run for awhile the buffer will dump and it will print. Likely what `sed` is waiting for as well. Thanks so much.

Comment: For anyone else running across this, I ran my original script above for a while with no output. Checked grep manpage for buffering options and found the `--line-buffered` option. Seems to be what I want. Performance hit is cautioned with it's use.